# Send encrypted password to CAS for TGT from restclient?

Tags: java, rest, security, cas

How can i send an encrypted password rather than hardcod password from java rest client for tgt creation in cas server.

Comment: It is not a clear question

Comment: I am generating a service ticket on cas for that first i need to generate a tgt for that i need to send username and password to cas server to login....but i need to send encrypted password , so that on cas console it is not visible

Comment: You should probably provide more details. If you are following Microsoft's model, you may have the machine key of the other host. Just send a message to the other host encrypted under the machine's key. Or if you have a shared key provided by the Key Distribution Center (KDC), you can encrypt the message with it, instead. (I think its the KDC that sets up the key shares).

Answer (score 1):

You send the encrypted password the same way you send any other password. It doesn't matter what the value is. You need to make sure the method of authentication you have enabled with CAS is able to decrypt the password if needed and get you authenticated correctly against the source. The REST API does not care what you send for a password.